# playframework polymorphic associations workflow

Tags: jpa, playframework, polymorphism

I need help with making one model belong to any other model, polymorphic way? As an example I'd like to use Comment model, which can belong to user, post and some other entity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through play's [basic tutorials](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home#guide) which demonstrate exactly that.

Comment: i read all the documentation, but I can't find polymorphic associations there, can u help me, sorry for being annoying!